# Synchronize Userprofile SP2013 VM with Active Directory

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, active-directory-import

I have a SP2013 DEV on a virtual machine and wonder if is possible to synchronize Userprofiler with Active directory of the company.

Comment: fix the link.Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VM on the domain then you can configure the User Profile services and create the sync connection.

Here are few guidline for you:

https://sharepointumar.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/configure-user-profile-service-application-in-sharepoint-2013/

[Synchronize user and group profiles in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx)

Comment: ThankS. Should I have Active directory installed in my VM ?

Comment: Is your company have AD? is your VM part of the Company's AD?

Comment: My company has AD. My VM is running on my company machine that is in doman. It's what you mean??

Comment: Ok then you just need to configure the user profile follow the article above. You dont need separate AD on your VM.

Comment: one more question, in your link I see that some action must done with active directory UI. can I install Ad without domain controller?

Comment: No you just need to make sure the account you are using in Sync connection having the correct permission. the step mentioned on the article is for "Replicate Directory changes" permission for the ID. it should be done on your company's AD